# Obfuscate 'import numpy as np'

Tags: python, import, module, obfuscation

I would like to import numpy under the alias np, but without using the code `import numpy as np`.

If possible, I would like to achieve this using vanilla python, with no external modules required.

Can this be done?

Comment: .......... why?

Comment: We like having some context... without context it's hard to notice if you have an XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: The problem is a human one. Ie, I would lose marks in an assessment because an automated marking script insists on 'import numpy'.

Comment: That sounds like an odd/weird choice on the part of your professor... I would bring it up. I would understand taking points off for something like `from numpy import *` or `import x, y, z` but otherwise, I can't think of any other form of `import` that I would consider to be bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This makes absolutely no sense, but you could do something like:

```
import numpy
np = numpy
del numpy
```

You now have the variable `np` which points at `numpy` without `numpy` being defined, and you never used the line `import numpy as np`.

Comment: Of course it makes no sense without context. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

The statement `import numpy as np` internally calls the `__import__` built in function, which you can call explicitly by saying `np = __import__('numpy')`.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

use [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__)  built-in

```
>>> np = __import__('numpy')
>>> np.__version__
'1.8.2'
```

Comment: This is an excat duplicate of my answer that I posted two minutes ago.

Comment: It probably took him two minutes to write the answer, it happens.